# Using a variable in a CSS selector

Tags: javascript, css-selectors

This might be a really silly question, but I have this CSS selector:

```
$('.result:nth-child(25) .name .title')
```

Which works. But when I set a variable a = 25, it breaks

```
$('.result:nth-child(a) .name .title')

 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: :nth-child
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps what you want is `$('.result:nth-child('+a+') .name .title')`

Comment: Not to be rude, but you can literally google your question title for an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to insert the value into the string manually in JavaScript using string concatenation. Try this instead:

```
$('.result:nth-child(' + a + ') .name .title')
```